# ObjectContext.Translate not working in oracle 19 version

Tags: oracle

this is my function that translate result from db to object classe.

```
public static List<T> GetListBySP<T>(string pSPName, params object[] pParamArray)
    {
        List<T> res = null;
        //string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[sConnStr].ConnectionString;
        string connStr = DbFactory.ConnStr;
        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connStr))
        {
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = pSPName;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                FillParameters(cmd.Parameters, pParamArray);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pCursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                using (var db = DbFactory.CreateRo())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.Connection.Open();
                        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                       
                        res = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Translate<T>(reader).ToList<T>();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        
                        throw ex;

                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        cmd.Connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

after update oracle version to 19.
exaption throw on line

```
res = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Translate<T>(reader).ToList<T>();
```

the exeption is:
An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.

the project run on .net framework 4.6.2

Comment: Not clear about Oracle versions: 11? 19? Or do you mean you after upgrading from 11 to 19? In that case, you probably moved from non-CDB to CDB/PDB configuration and your connection string must be updated, e.g. ":SID" should be replaced by "/SERVICENAME", where most often the service name is the name of the PDB.

Comment: @p3consulting Yes, you are right, there was an upgrade from version 11 to 19. this is the format of my connection string ' how to updatee this? connectionString="User Id=oracle_user;Password=oracle_user_password;Data Source=oracle"

Comment: you show the pattern of the connection string but the value of "oracle" should be "<HOST/service_name>" instead of "<HOST:SID>" as far as I can see in Oracle's doc related to .Net.